# Advice on having videos on the device vs an alternative

Tags: ios4

I am working on an App that will have a bunch of pictures and videos the user will need to have. The app's mantra is having these videos and pictures available on demand and on the go.  However, I am concerned about the app being too fat (big), in essence turning off some customers who prioritize size over substance. The preference has always been to have the customer be able to access these videos from anywhere regardless of 3g/wifi (i.e. local on the device). What are the really good options? Assuming I choose to elect to go the non-local route (i.e. using wifi/3g), what are my options there as well? Please advice. The size of the videos/pics could be up to 1.5GB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual approach seems to be to download and store the videos on demand. A lot of the apps I've seen allow the user to manage the stored videos themselves so that they can remove videos if they aren't going to use them again.